# mapping subdomain to a server

Tags: dns, subdomain

Say I have a domain called www.test.com and I have a subdomain called www.test.one.com. I want to be able to map www.test.one.com to a web server different from the web server of www.test.com, is such thing possible?

Comment: In your example, www.test.one.com is **not** a subdomain of www.test.com, it's a subdomain of one.com

Comment: yes.. I just realized that mistake, my apology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [name-based virtual host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service) support in whatever web server you're using. Configure DNS to point both names to the same IP address, and configure your server to hand out different content based on server name.

Or, if you're flush with IP addresses, give each a different IP address, and configure your server to serve different content on each IP address.